# Generate code Simulink/Stateflow

Tags: simulink, stateflow

I generate C++ code using Simulink; Simulink builds `file.exe` but it doesn't run. The problem is:

> the program can't start because libmx.dill is missing from your
>   computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

By the way the file `libmx.dll` already exists in the Matlab path. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try running the exe from within MATLAB using

```
>> system('my.exe');
```

does it work?

If yes, then the most likely cause is that the directory containing libmx.dll isn't on your *system* path.